# Custom CSS style collection in Angular

Tags: angular

I am building a component library for my company, and want my components to be easily stylable by providing an input property similar to this:

```
interface ComponentCSS {
 root: { [klass: string]: any };
 icon: { [klass: string]: any };
}

@Input()
styles: ComponentCSS;
```

But I am yet to find out how to use it the HTML code to style my component. I have tried this:

```
<app-component styles="{root:{'background': 'crimson'}}"></app-component>
```

But it complains that styles "cannot be a string"... but that is how you are supposed to write these things, right?

Is there a built-in way of doing this more properly?

Comment: You're getting the error because you pass the object as string. Instead of using a normal attribute `styles="..."` (which expects a string) you should use `[styles]="..."` which allows you to pass in the object.

Comment: Ah, that lead me to the solution thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it turned out if someone needs a similar solution:

In component file:

```
interface ComponentCSS {
  root: { [Klass: string]: any };
}

@Input()
css_styles: ComponentCSS;
```

In component HTML:

```
<div
  class="component-root"
  [ngStyle]="css_styles.root"
  ...></div>
```

Setting the custom CSS:

```
<app-component
  [css_styles]="{root:{ 'background': 'red' }}">
</app-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `styles` is a reserved keyword for inline HTML styles. I would try to use another name for the `Input` property.

Comment: That was not it, renaming it to anything else still yields that it cannot be a string error.